# Unity webplayer crashes with UI text (new canvas text)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I just finished the Space Shooter tutorial and since there was no `GUIText` object I created `UI.Text` objects instead and coded accordingly. It works in the unity player but not after building the web application. It took me a while to pinpoint the bug but when i completely dissabled the `UI.Text` and rebuild I got it to work.

The web player displays: *The content was stopped because a fatal content error has been detected.* followed by a crash report.

Is there any fix for this? Or perhaps a temporary workaround to use text?

Comment: what does the crash report say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem following the same tutorial. Check your settings at `Edit/Project Settings/Graphics`. If you have only one shader added (Diffuse), include 'UI/Default' and 'UI/Default Font'.

Now, I'm new to Unity so I cannot further describe the fix. But apparently, the UI Texts are the only objects in the scene (if you followed the tutorial) which have a Material property with `None (Material)` set as value. My guess is that with that value set the shaders mentioned above are needed, but not bundled automatically when creating the builds. Read [Unity GraphicsSettings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GraphicsSettings.html) for information.

Why did I add those? Because those are included by default in other projects following other Unity tutorials.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. There is nothing out there addressing this problem and I imagine a lot of people hit this wall with the new version.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but when I opened the Graphics panel, I found that UI/Default and UI/Default Font were already there.  I then tried to create my own material, set it to be a UI/Default Font shader and assigned it to all three of my text objects.  After this, I was able to run my PC build without crashing but the web build continued to crash.  (Strangely, the Roll-a-ball tutorial also uses UI.Text, but it runs in my web broswer fine).